# Postcode lookup that redirects user to nearest store page?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-field, google-maps

I have searched high and low for a Wordpress solution that would let me have a simple text field where a user inputs their postcode or area, and then the field lookups the lat/long assigned to various pages of my website and redirects them to their nearest store's webpage. I have seen this solution in use on other sites like this one: https://helpinghandshomecare.co.uk but I can't find a simple way of achieving this.

Any advice is welcome.